# Prevent same domain iframe to access scope of surrounding window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that displays a web page from the same domain as the main window (but that I  cannot control directly).
It is crucial for my application, that I manipulate the html of the iframe's web page - which means insertion of event handlers.

However, I want to make it impossible that the iframe may manipulate the main window, like, for example, with a script like this

```
window.parent.location.href = 'http://wwww.somewhereelse.com';
```

or

```
window.parent.getElementById('123').innerHTML = 'anything';
```

In short, I want an iframe that I can manipulate from the surrounding scope, but that can not manipulate the surrounding scope vice versa. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

If I prepend `window.parent = null` to the iframe's html, this will foreceably prevent the iframe from accessing the outer scope.

Comment: It won't. That leaves `window.top` open … and even if it didn't: nothing is preventing the framed document from copying a the value of `window.parent` to another variable before you can inject the null assignment.

Comment: not if I prepend it, thus, having it executed before any other code within the iframe.

Comment: but you are right about window.top. Unfortunately, at least within chrome, it is not possible to set `window.top = null` (readonly property)

Comment: Since you can't control it directly, the only way to do that would be to access its DOM through the iframe, but there's no way to do that and guarantee that no script on the page will execute first.

Comment: I access the iframe's content via ajax and insert it on `iframe.on("load")`. So yes, I can guarantee the sequence of execution.

Comment: still, I would absolutely prefer a different solution